# Improving performance of views

Tags: sql, performance, view, indexing

I have a view that manages record-level authority. For this sake, we'll call it an "AuthorityView". It works by viewing underlying tables, the actual "Data", a "Record Authority" table, and a "Usergroups" table.

For this example, we are selecting "Employee" records. There is a core table, "EmployeeData", which contains all the data, an "EmployeeRecordAuthority", which specifies what user groups have what access to the data (read, read/write, update, delete, etc), and "Usergroups" simply stores which groups users belong to.

The view uses a join which is fairly simple, but processes a lot of records (~100k employee records and ~3m record authority records). The end result is a subset of records which the user can view.

The problem I am having is that querying the view with no criteria is very slow. It is taking around 6-7 minutes to do a "select * from EmployeeAuthorityView", however, applying a "top" to it makes it perform as expected. "Select top 10000000 * from EmployeeAuthorityView" takes mere seconds.

All relevant indexes exist between the tables, and have been rebuilt.

What could be causing the slow down in querying? Why is it quicker to query with a "top" limit specified, even though the quantity is far greater than the number of records in the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this be Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, or other RDBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in performance is probably because of different strategies that the database query optimizer uses to retrieve your data.

The exact reason depends on which DBMS you are using, and how its query optimizer is written, but the problem arises from the concept of a “view with no criteria”, and is something like the following.

Your EmployeeAuthorityView looks like a join of the Data, RecordAuthority and UserGroups tables.  So the view itself, without any filtering criteria, defines a theoretical set which is the product (outer join) of those tables.  That theoretical set contains 100,000 x 3,000,000 x U records (U is the size of your UserGroups table).  As soon as you apply some selection criteria, the size of the theoretical set is reduced drastically, but with no criteria it’s trillions of records (assuming that your UserGroups table has more than 3 rows).

How many records of this theoretical set does the DBMS need to instantiate, before it can give you a buffer full?  The query optimizer considers multiple strategies, including (Strategy A) create all 300U billion records before returning the first buffer full to your app, (Strategy B) just create records as it needs them, returning a buffer full to your app as soon as it has that many.  Factors that affect that choice are, among others, “in what order does it need to return records to your app”.  Using the “top” limit causes the order to be defined differently, and in this case it chooses something like strategy B.